# Чтение из файла в строковый массив (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, массивы, imacros

Необходимо из локального файла, который является списком ссылок (разделитель - перенос строки) создать массив. Количество элементов массива задается переменной, файл используется один и тот-же, сохраненный на локальном диске (или в облаке). Каким образом записать данные из этого файла в строковый массив на языке **JavaScript**? Прошу вас дать кусок кода отвечающего за запись массива, или ссылку на литературу дающую возможность написать данный код (конкретно импорт элементов в массив из файла). Заранее премного благодарен.

*P.S. Данный кусок кода будет использован в скрипте iMacros для автоматизации удаления "мертвых" участников сообщества VK. Список ссылок получается из отдельного приложения VK.*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В стандарте HTML5 описан [File API](https://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/), предоставляющий доступ к чтению содержимого файлов на локальном компьютере ([поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=file%20api) всеми основными браузерами). Прочитать можно не любой файл, только тот, который был выбран пользователем при помощи элемента `<input type="file"/>`. Основными классами, с которыми придётся иметь дело будут `File` и `FileReader`. Вот простой пример их использования, более подробно - [здесь](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) или в [документации](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications).

```js
// Проверяем, поддерживает ли браузер нужные API
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
      // Если бы у input[type=file] был параметр multiple, пользователь смог бы выбрать
     // несколько файлов, а в e.target.files было бы больше одного элемента
      var file = e.target.files[0];
      // Для демонстрации прочитаем файл и выведем каждую его строку как элемент списка
      var output = document.getElementById('output');
      var reader = new FileReader();
      // Устанавливаем обработчик события onload. Оно произойдёт по окончанию чтения файла
      reader.onload = function(e) {
          // e.target.result содержит всё содержимое файла
          var text = e.target.result;
          // Разбиваем строку на элементы, разделителем служит исмвол перевода строки \n
          var array = text.split('\n');
        
          // Для демонстрации того, что файл прочитался и разбился на строки правильно,
          // рисуем список, элементами которого будут строки файла
          output.innerHTML = '<ul>';
          for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       output.innerHTML += '<li>' + array[i] + '</li>';
          }
          output.innerHTML += '</ul>';
      };
      
      // Начинаем чтение выбранного файла
      reader.readAsText(file);
    });
} else {
    alert('File API is not supported!');
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

Чтение произвольных файлов реализовано только в Chrome в виде экспериментального [Filesystem API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API). Также беспрепятственный доступ к файловой системе имеют браузерные расширения, но их придётся писать для каждого браузера отдельно.

Если же вас интересует чтение файла из облака, используйте [XMLHttpRequest](http://xmlhttprequest.ru/) для получения его содержимого. Возможно, вам придётся передавать данные авторизации, чтобы получить доступ к файлу.

Comment: Сразу упираюсь в ограничение: в iMacros реализована возможность применения только JavaScript или собственного языка iMacros. Насколько я понял, в JS не реализована API взаимодействия с файлами. Тогда можно заменить выбор файла, на ввод текста (содержимое буффера обмена) через строковою переменную. В этом случае код упростится. Значительных изменений не будет? Вместо *"e.target.result"* будет переменная, в которую в самом начале будет выливаться содержимое буфера?

Comment: Все, спасибо за помощь, но обнаружил другую возможность реализации макроса используя только язык iMacros (!datasources).

Answer (score 0):

File Api нужен для других целей. Чтобы его использовать - вам необходимо будет открывать диалог выбора файла, выбирать там файл и только после этого вы сможете прочитать с него данные. Либо перетаскивать файл из проводника в браузер.
Никак иначе вы не сможете прочитать файл через File Api из-за политики безопасности браузера.

iMacros позволяет использовать огромное количество функционала, доступного при написании расширений, например нормальное чтение\запись в файл. Стандартные функции iMacros, а в особенности !DATASOURCE и прочее, слишком ужасно реализовано и позволяет работать только с csv-форматом.

Вот вам кусочек кода для чтения\записи в любой файл с примерами, немного его переписал под вашу задачу:

```
var helper = {

    /**
     *  Load file
     */
    loadFile: function (fileName) {
        var file_i = imns.FIO.openNode(file);       
        return imns.FIO.readTextFile(file_i).split('\r\n');     
    },

    /**
     *  Save file
     */
    saveFile: function (fileName, content) {
        var file_i = imns.FIO.openNode(filename);
        imns.FIO.writeTextFile(file_i, content);
    }

};

/*
    ===Example - test.txt:===
    test1
    test2
    test3
 */


// How use
var arrayOfLines = helper.loadFile("c:\\test.txt"); // arrayofLines = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

helper.saveFile("c:\\test.txt", "content of file, any text"); // saving into file
```